# Fuzzy search with Solr and sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, fuzzy-search

I have installed Solr and the Sunspot gem for my Rails 3.0 app.

My goal is to do fuzzy search.
For example, I want the search term "Chatuea Marguxa" be found as "Château Margaux".

Actually, only the same exact words are found, so fuzzy didn't work at all.

My model:

```
  searchable do
    text :winery
  end
```

My controller:

```
   search = Wine.search do
     fulltext 'Chatuea Marguxa'
   end
```

The solr schemas I tried, with ngrams:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
  </analyzer>
```

I also tried with double metaphone:

```
<analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
      </analyzer>
```

In both cases, I got 0 response. (after reindexing of course).

What I did wrong ?

Comment: a phonetic filter does not suffice in your case, you need spell checking / correction

Comment: What tool can I use for that ? I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

try to add character `'~'` behind all word in query. Like this: `Chatuea~ Marguxa~`. This is fuzzy operator implemented in lucene: http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches

Answer (score 0):

some searching around revealed [fuzzily](http://dec0de.me/2012/10/fuzzily-released/) gem:

> Anecdotical benchmark: against our whole Geonames-derived table of
>   locations (3.2M records, about 1GB of data), on my development machine
>   (a 2011 MacBook Pro)
>
> searching for the top 10 matching records takes 6ms ±1 preparing the
>   index for all records takes about 10min the DB query overhead when
>   changing a record is at 3ms ±2 the memory overhead (footprint of the
>   trigrams table index) is about 300MB